# 4d Integral in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to evaluate the integral using MATLAB with an equation containing 4 related random variables, thus the boundaries of the integrals are not constant.

There are 2 exponential pdfs, and 2 other hyper exponential , and 1 Reyleigh CDF all multiplied together and with (x - y - z).

I'm trying to evaluate it using integral $Q = (@(w) integral3(@(x,y,z,w),xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax),wmin,wmax);$

I'm getting an error always. this is my code down here :

```
u_x = 10; %  rate!
x_th = .3;
sigma = 1.33;
u_y = 10;
u_w = 100;
a= 1;
fun = @(x,y,z,w) (x - y - z )*u_x*exp(-u_x*x)*u_y*exp(-u_y*y)*((a/(a+1))*(a*u_w)*exp(-a*u_w*w)+((1/(a+1))*(u_w/a))*exp(-u_w*w/a))*((a/(a+1))*(a*u_w)*exp(-a*u_w*z)+((1/(a+1))*(u_w/a))*exp(-u_w*z/a))*(1-exp(-x_th/sigma^2))

xmin = @(y)y;
xmax = @(y,w)y + w;
ymin = 0;
ymax = inf;
zmin = 0;
zmax = @(w) w;
wmin = 0;
wmax = inf;

Q = integral(@(w) integral3(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax),wmin,wmax);
```

ERROR MESSAGE :

Error using integral3 (line 63)
XMIN must be a floating point scalar.

Error in numerical_int>@(w)integral3(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax)

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 83)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in numerical_int (line 28)
Q = integral(@(w) integral3(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax),wmin,wmax);

Comment: Can you give the link to the forum please?

Comment: Or perhaps [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I'm no MatLab expert, but [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is sometimes useful.

Comment: I have no idea if it helps, but try to add a dot before every multiplication etc.